# “Punheta de bacalhau”? Por que “punheta”? Qual a origem?

Tags: etimologia, diferenças-transatlânticas, origem, termos

I've come across the picture of a portuguese dish, namely “punheta de bacalhau”, and found it strange because in pt-BR   “punheta” is a vulgar word for the most common form of male masturbation. Why  “punheta” in such a context as “punheta de bacalhau”?  When and where did the term originate?  Does the word “punheta” also mean, in pt-PT, what it does in pt-BR?

Comment: Acho que descobri a origem do termo.

Comment: @Jacinto  Então conte-nos.

Comment: Já editei a resposta. Basicamente, a *espinheta de atum* é uma parte do atum, com espinha. Portanto é natural, que no bacalhau fosse também isso.

Comment: punheta não é um verbo. Acho que é preciso usar o verbo bater.....

Comment: @Lambie   In an informal and very personal context, there's the verb "punhetar", which isn't exactly the same as "bater" ou "tocar" punheta.  It doesn't  necessarily means a complete masturbation with orgasm but merely the movement one does with one's hand and arm..

Comment: bater punheta is to jack off, excuse me, It is a metaphor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

***Punheta*** é punheta também em Portugal, e é igualmente uma palavra a evitar em sociedade delicada. [Priberam, *Punheta*:](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/punheta)

> *substantivo feminino*
>   1. [Calão]  Masturbação masculina.

A origem do nome ***punheta de bacalhau*** está enterrada na cultura oral popular. Este [artigo do Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/espinheta-e-punheta-de-bacalhau-culinaria/23981) não chega a grandes conclusões. Mas pelo que consegui apurar, o mais provável é que ***punheta*** seja aqui uma modificação brejeira de ***espinheta***, que por sua vez designaria o rabo (cauda) do bacalhau.

Uma busca pela net revela que ***punheta de bacalhau*** e ***espinheta de bacalhau*** designam o mesmo prato: bacalhau cru desfiado, temperado com cebola, alho, azeite, e ainda salsa ou coentros, pimenta e vinagre a gosto (varia de site para site). Nalguns sites, [como este](http://www.saborintenso.com/f94/punheta-bacalhau-ou-espinheta-salada-2024/), aparecem os dois nomes. [Neste blog (2009)](http://artes-viagens-sabores.blogspot.pt/2009/06/punheta-de-bacalhau.html) uma participante relata uma experiência de infância que sugere que ***punheta*** era uma corrupção de ***espinheta*** vista com maus olhos por alguns:

> Ai meu Deus! Não havia necessidade! Onde está o provedor dos blogs!!!
>
> Não é punheta, Santo Deus! O nome no prato é espinheta de bacalhau!!! Espinheta significa “sem espinhas”.
>
> Por causa da punheta e da espinheta levei um dia um valente puxão de orelhas da minha avó. Nunca mais me esqueci!!!

Que *espinheta* signifique “sem espinhas” é que me parece altamente duvidoso, até porque exitem imensos pratos de bacalhau sem espinhas, e mais nenhum se chama *espinheta*. Mas mais importante, existe a ***espinheta de atum***, uma posta do atum descrita aqui em [*Outras Comidas*](http://outrascomidas.blogspot.pt/2012/11/espinheta-de-atum.html) por alguém que comeu uma:

> A espinheta, também chamada espinheira, é, como o nome indica, a espinha do atum e as espinhas ligadas às barbatanas dorsais, tiradas com grande quantidade de carne quando os grandes atuns são desmanchados.

[*Espinheta* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/espinheta) aparece nos dicionários apenas como variante de [*espineta* (Priberam)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/espineta), que é um instrumento musical predecessor do cravo, sem relação com peixe. Mas na indústria ***espinheta*** é mesmo usado com o significado acima, como se pode ver aqui na [página das *Conservas Dâmaso*](https://www.facebook.com/188571737852690/photos/pb.188571737852690.-2207520000.1458777972./188574467852417/?type=3&theater).

Portanto, parece-me plausível que ***espinheta*** designasse também a parte mais espinhosa do bacalhau, que é (tirando a cabeça, conhecida por *caras*, que não se presta a este prato) a cauda, conhecida em Portugal por *rabo do bacalhau*. Ora eu não conhecia a punheta de bacalhau, mas o nosso JorgeB. informou-me que a mãe dele a fazia sempre com o rabo do bacalhau, porque usar os lombos para a punheta seria um «crime» e «os lombos são bons para outros pratos». E não é só na casa dele. Nesta receita de [*punheta de bacalhau à moda da Gafanha*](http://cozinha-do-zezao.blogspot.pt/2014/08/punheta-de-bacalhau-moda-da-gafanha.html), o autor começa por dizer:

> neste caso usei um rabo de bacalhau graúdo muito usado também para estes fins.

Portanto parece-me que o mais provável é que *espinheta* designasse na linguagem popular e da arte uma parte do peixe incluindo parte da espinha dorsal e com relativamente muita espinha e pouco peixe, como é o caso do rabo do bacalhau; daí passasse a designar um prato comummente feito com ela; e que tenha sido deliberadamente corrompido em *punheta*.

Que alguém se lembrasse de chamar *punheta* à *espinheta*, e que o novo nome se espalhasse como fogo em mato seco, não me parece nada de extraordinário: a semelhança fonética e a brejeirice do pessoal seriam suficientes. Talvez a simplicidade e rapidez de preparação do prato sugerissem também uma analogia entre a punheta enquanto ato sexual e a punheta de bacalhau no quadro de confeções mais elaboradas.

Não consegui foi apurar quando é que os vários termos apareceram. No Google Books há uma dúzia de ocorrências de *punheta de bacalhau*, e a mais antiga é apenas de 1992. É quase certo que o nome na cultura oral é muito mais antigo. Há uma ***pívia de bacalhau*** de 1984, que só pode ter surgindo depois de *punheta*. *Espinheta de bacalhau* nem sequer se encontra:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Encontrei uma única *espinheta* que tivesse a ver com peixe [(A. Vicente Campinas, *A Prova Real*, 1960):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=rzYRAQAAMAAJ&q=espinheta&dq=espinheta&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjks8GW2prNAhUrBMAKHSTaAPoQ6AEIbTAM)

> A mulher acabara de juntar a espinheta de atum às batatas. E deixava escorrer, do frasco com excessivo zelo, o delgado fio de azeite no prato quando o apito soou.

Por curiosidade, existe na Bahia a ***punheta de estudante***, também conhecido  simplesmente por *punheta* (Houaiss):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: E agora fiquei com vontade de comer uma depois da tua descrição da receita :D

Comment: @JorgeB. Pelos vistos isto é prato ribatejano. Na minha zona, Torres Vedras, que não é muito longe, fazia-se era com bacalhau assado.

Comment: não fazia ideia, sempre achei que era nortenho.

Comment: Come-se cru ?...

Comment: @Centaurus Exatamente. [Tens aqui a preparação em vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N73LDlDVsI) em menos de 3 minutos. O artigo da espinheta que eu cito diz que era o tipo de coisa que os campinos que andavam pelos campos a cavalo podiam preparar facilmente.

Comment: Entendo que funciona mais como um prato "quebra-galho", porque é fácil de ser preparado (com as proprias mãos), em qualquer lugar, e rapidamente.   Estarei em terras lusitanas dentro de alguns dias e talvez experimente a iguaria.

Comment: @Centaurus experimenta também o bacalhau assado na brasa é muito bom.

Comment: @Centaurus Não é propriamente rápido de preparar (em qualquer lado), porque tem de se demolhar o bacalhau. Mas lá simples, é.

Comment: @ANeves punheta de bacalhau é feita com bacalhau salgado, não se demolha.

Comment: @JorgeB. punheta de bacalhau é feita com bacalhau demolhado, demolha-se. Olha, no link que o Jacinto partilhou de um vídeo com instruções sobre como a preparar, um sujeito a usar para isso [`uma posta de bacalhau, já previamente dessalgada`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1N73LDlDVsI&feature=youtu.be&t=45)... sim, OK, ele é um energúmeno por usar lombos para punheta; mas independentemente disso, usa bacalhau demolhado. A punheta é um prato húmido (salvo seja); nunca a vi feita com bacalhau seco.

Comment: @ANeves vou confirmar com a minha mãe, mas eu tenho a ideia que era com ele salgado, ou se não era salgado era quase... Mas vou confirmar isso ainda hoje.

Comment: "A punheta é um prato húmido"   "húmido" com "h"  ?  É assim em Portugal?

Comment: @Márcio Osório  Mesmo depois do acordo ortográfico ?

Comment: Sim, @Centaurus, «húmido» [é assim com h](https://dicionario.priberam.org/h%C3%BAmido) em portugal.

Answer (score 3):

A "punheta de bacalhau" deriva do Bacalhau de Punhete (antigo nome da Vila de Constância. Punhete ficava na confluência do Tejo com o rio Zêzere (Ozezere) denominado por aquelas gentes apenas de Rio. Ou seja, havia o Tejo e o Rio. Tudo leva a crer que o Zêzere (antes Ozêzere) significasse "O de César" imperador romano. Por corruptela ficou Ozêzere e depois Zêzere. Os Avieiros, gentes vindas da Vieira de Leiria, em busca de substencia no Tejo, por ali ficaram com os seus carinhos (barcos de pesca) e muitos levavam os produtos da terra para a grande cidade Lisboa. Aí se encontravam com os marcadores que vinham do norte da Europa, nomeadamente noruegueses e dinamarqueses de quem obtinham, subrrepticiamente, fardos de bacalhau que, de imediato, colocavam na água para não ficar à vista (tipo candonga). Ao chegarem a Punhete, esse bacalhau demolhado, era de imediato desfiado e colocado em alguidares e distribuído pelas mulheres que os aguardavam. Daí o bacalhau à Punhete, derivando para punheta de bacalhau. Esta é a verdadeira história do nome do prato típico da gastronomia nacional.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Portugueses Language! Tem alguma fonte que corrobore esta versão?

Comment: +1 por de facto a [Vila de Constância](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const%C3%A2ncia_(Portugal)) em tempos se ter de facto chamado Punhete.