# Qual o significado de "foda" em Feira da Foda?

Tags: significado, português-europeu, expressões, regionalismo

Já ouvi falar muito da Feira da Foda, com elogios a tudo aquilo que pode-se comer no evento. Qual a origem da denominação "Feira da Foda" e qual o significado de "foda" nesse caso. No Brasil, "foda" é um termo chulo e, que seja do meu conhecimento,  significa exclusivamente o ato sexual, seja ele entre humanos ou não.

Comment: O dicionário português [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/foda) diz que *foda* significa principalmente o ato sexual. Porém, no Minho, também significa “cordeiro assado em alguidar de barro levado a forno de lenha, típico de Monção, no Minho”. Imagino que os portugueses também achem graça.

Comment: @Schilive  Mas porque deram o nome de foda ao cordeiro?

Comment: Centaurus, não sei. nada de certo Este [site](https://www.diarioluso-galaico.com/articulo/recomendado/o-maria-ja-meteste-a-foda/20210331181127019773.html) conta que veio do xingamento mesmo.

Comment: @Centaurus a explicação intuitiva que um português daria para isso é que faz parte da boa disposição de dizer um palavrão, é como a [punheta de bacalhau](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3334/) ou chamarem "cacete" a um pão no Algarve. Eu nunca tinha ouvido falar da *"Feira da Foda"* mas ao ver no google que é associado a uma terra especifica (ou seja Pias em Monção) diria que é um micro-regionalismo maluco da boa disposição que só pode ser levado nesse sentido. Quanto mais antigo for uso do termo mais legitimo é, se for modernice não tem valor.

Comment: Nesse contexto tens de perceber que os locais já conhecendo o sentido do termo ou não ligam ou riem-se, e quem é de fora fica surpreendido ou embaraçado. A função social do termo esgota-se por ai, se conheceres alguém da terra ficas a conhecer o termo, é um bocado o cartão de visita da terra. (Não queiras comparar esse uso aos neologismos do funk que já darão para encher um dicionário do calão especializado, é muito diferente por ser uso isolado e circunscrito.)